# Is there a Mobile Push _Open data view

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, mobilepush

Is there a _Open data view for mobile push equivalent to Channel email? I cannot find any https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5 but the Mobile Push Studio tracks the opens - that means SFMC has the data somewhere.

Usecases: Journey Engagement Splits and Goal Tracking (who of the contacts opened the push and booked a product)

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment but it was [posted as an idea in the Trailblazer community](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdbSQUAZ/data-view-for-mobile-push).

For now, your only option is a [MobilePush Detail Extract Report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_run_the_mobilepush_detail_extract_report.htm&type=5) or you can try using a third-party solution in AppExchange.