# MobilePush - Track Push Notifications' Opens

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, mobilepush, custom-reports, push-notification

One of our customers has asked a detailed report of users who opened a push notification. Is there such a report or some sort of a data view to query from? would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but Opens can be found under basic push reports . Do you want to make it an automatic process ?

Comment: Similar thread can be found in here . https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/257401/31481

Comment: You are right Pragyanshu, I've actually created a report before asking a question here but I was missing the "MessageOpened" attribute. Thanks a lot!